# Does the List-A matches include One day internationals

Tags: cricket, statistics, icc

I saw the profiles of [Sachin](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/35320.html), [Ponting](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/7133.html), [Pietersen](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/19296.html) and some other international players.

All that stats shows that no. of their List-A matches are greater than no of their Odis,this only raised me the question,

"Does the List-A matches include One day internationals"

None of the players had their stats in list-A matches less than their ODI's stats.

The no. of their First-class matches and Twenty20 matches are greater than no of their Tests and T20I stats respectively.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this in a simple way:

- **Tests** -> 5 day games that a player plays for his/her national team.
- **ODIs** -> 50 over games that a player plays for his/her national team.
- **T20Is** -> 20 over games that a player plays for his/her national team.
- **First-class** -> International test matches + Test matches in domestic leagues.
- **List A** -> ODIs + 50 over games played in domestic leagues.
- **T20** -> T20Is + 20 over games played in domestic leagues.

Comment: +1,any references? then I'll accept it

Comment: "A player's first-class statistics include his performances in Test matches." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_cricket. Similarly, List A includes ODI stats and T20 includes T20I.

Comment: This is a bit overly simplistic. For example, [Canada vs Netherlands](http://www.espncricinfo.com/world-cricket-league-div2-2015/engine/match/812777.html) from January 2015 is not counted as a one-day international despite being a 50 over match between national teams.